# itunes U identification problem

Tags: itunes, podcasts, authentication

I have registered myself on the apple developer program. Now when I try to access the podcasts I can't download some of them or even watch them. The only thing what happens is that I get a iTunes U folder where the podcast resides whit the error message:

```
When loading "Session 216 - Time Machine Indepth" an error occurred  
Identification required to access "http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/iTunesAuthAction/getFile.mov?....some long string...."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you logged into the same iTunes user name associated with your Developer login? Have you logged in via [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/)?

Comment: Yes, I even have to login first to developer.apple.com to even get to the podcasts. Without this I am not able the see the developer section in itunes